# Flattening lakes for hydro-flattened DEM using polygon vertices in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, interpolation, surface

I have the vertices around lake polygons that I want to flatten for a hydro-flattened DEM. I know that ArcGIS has a trend tool that will create a sloped 'plane of best fit' for a series of points, however the best I can find in QGIS is the IDW interpolation tool, which doesn't create a completely flat surface.

Does anyone know of a QGIS tool/workflow that will do this?

Edit: Lake surfaces should be completely flat, it's large rivers that require a trend surface.

Comment: Do you have lakes with heights as XYZ polygons?

Comment: No the lakes are just X and Y, I extracted the vertices from the polygon then sampled the DEM at those point locations to get XYZ points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a sloped 'plane of best fit', try **Polynomial regression** tool in the `Processing Toolbox > SAGA > Geostatistics`.

Below, the image shows the elevation data (`elev`) stored in the attribute table.

[image]

Activate `Polynomial regression` tool and choose `Simple planar surface` from polynom options. It will create a fitted surface grid and calculated residual.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The best method that I have found is using scipy nd image labeling and statistics to do a minimum elevation void filling process in python.

Comment: Hi @Alex and welcome to GIS.stackexchange. Could you add some example code to your answer to make it easier to reproduce for other ?